# How should I inherit from a built-in?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, built-in

I want to give a class I made all of the methods that a string has (`replace`, `isupper`, etc.)
Below is some example code:

```
>>> class MyClass(str):
...     def __init__(self, string):
...         self.string = string
...     def __str__(self):
...         return self.string
...
>>> MyClass("aaa").replace("a", "$")
'$$$'
>>>
```

This works exactly as I want it to.  However, I am a little confused on how I should inherit from `str`.  I can do as I did above, or:

```
class MyClass(__builtins__.str):
    ...
```

or even:

```
import types
class MyClass(types.__builtins__["str"]):
```

Summed up, my question is: what is the best way to inherit from `str` (or any other built-in for that matter)?  Did I give it or is there an even better way I'm not thinking of.

Thanks.

Comment: You should, generally, not concern yourself with `__builtins__`. Just use `str` directly. But, is there an actual problem here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - No, there is nothing wrong with using `str` directly.  I just wanted some clarification on what is the best way to inherit from a built-in.  Since there are a few ways to do what I want, I like to choose the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Never touch `__builtins__`.** It is an implementation detail. Quoting the docs for the confusingly similarly-named [`__builtin__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) module:

> CPython implementation detail: Most modules have the name `__builtins__` (note the 's') made available as part of their globals. The value of `__builtins__` is normally either this module or the value of this modules’s **dict** attribute. Since this is an implementation detail, it may not be used by alternate implementations of Python.

Just inherit from `str`. There's no reason not to; it's not faster or clearer or anything to use some other name for it.

Comment: Cool.  That is what I thought.  Just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass(str):
```

Is just fine. I do not think there is a problem with that. Why do you want to burden yourself by using `builtin` and all...